# How do you sort files in different directories by date modified using powershell?

Tags: powershell

Can anyone show me how to get the newest test.txt file from two different directories, C: and T: and store it into a variable?

So there are two identical files that exist, one on each drive. Which is newer? Store the newest into a variable to use later!

Thanks so much

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see this page for how to ask a clear question, which will help you to get the answers your looking for.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Try using Get-Item: `$(Get-Item "<myfile>").LastWriteTime`

Comment: Your title is asking for something different from what your question body is asking. Which do you want?

Comment: Hi Tyler, thanks for the comment. I want to look at two files with the same name that exists on C: and T: Then I want to grab whichever is never and throw it into a variable. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

As for...

> How do you sort files by date modified using powershell?

You can get examples of how to do this by using the help files.

```
# Get a list of all functions
Get-Command -CommandType Function | 
Out-GridView -PassThru -Title 'Available functions'


# Get a list of all commandlets
Get-Command -CommandType Cmdlet | 
Out-GridView -PassThru -Title 'Available cmdlets'


# get function / cmdlet details
(Get-Command -Name Get-ChildItem).Parameters
Get-help -Name Get-ChildItem -Examples
Get-help -Name Get-ChildItem -Full
Get-help -Name Get-ChildItem -Online

(Get-Command -Name Sort-Object).Parameters
Get-help -Name Sort-Object -Examples
Get-help -Name Sort-Object -Full
Get-help -Name Sort-Object -Online


# Get paarameter that accept pipeline input
Get-Help Get-ChildItem -Parameter * | 
Where-Object {$_.pipelineInput -match 'true'} | 
Select * 


Get-Help about_*
Get-Help about_Functions
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do it:

```
$fileList = Get-ChildItem -Path c:\temp -Recurse file.txt | Sort-Object LastwriteTime -Descending | select -first 1
```

The will raise the most recent one to the top of the list (using Sort-Object) and then if you select the first in the list you've got your most recent file.

Comment: Hi Matt, Thanks a lot for your answer. I have tried this and I'm not sure this is for multiple directories? I need to be comparing the same file from C: and from T: to check which is newer, thanks again for the help!